# Custom Swing Component Update Delayed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, java-7

**DEMO Files can be downloaded here**: [github](https://github.com/maltebargholz/GOL-Java)

I'm trying implement Conways Game Of Life in Java Swing. Everything works except automatic stepping. My Interface simply lags behind the model all the time.

[image]

The basic Model of my application is the following:

**View:**

`view.GOLView`: A runnable class which construct the interface and then adds a `view.GridPanel` of the given grid size.

`view.GridPanel` Extends `JPanel` and initializes an Array of `view.GridCellComponents` which are layouted in a `GridLayout`. Each `view.GridCellComponent` is a subclass of `JComponent` which overrides the `paintComponent()` method. It also contains a method which takes two indices and a value which updates the corresponding `GridCellComponent` which then updates its internal state and calls `this.paintImmediately(..)`.

**Model:**

`model.GOLField` holds the current field a `boolean[][]` array and contains a `synchronized` method to calculate the next step. The `nextStep` method returns an `ArrayList` with the changed indices.

**Controller:**

`controller.GOLController` The class which contains the main method. It initializes a `view.GOLView` class and a `model.GOLField` class and the calls `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(view)`.

**The Problem:**

When the next step should be calculated I call `nextStep` on the `GOLField` and iterate over each change returned by it and call the `updateCell` function on `GOLView`. The passes the update down onto the corresponding `GridCellComponent` which then calls `this.paintImmediately()`. 
This works fine when called once, but when i try to automate this the internal state (in `GOLField`) gets updated fine but the interface lags behind.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Using a thread which executes `nextStep` , updates the interface and then `Thread.sleep()` for 250 ms.
- Using a `SwingTimer` which does the same.
- Using a `SwingWorker` which calls `nextStep` in `doInBackground` and updates the interface in `done`.
- Using a regular Timer which does the same as the `SwingTimer` but calls `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the interface.

Every single one of these methods exhibit the same problem. `nextStep` gets called fine and the model updates in the background but the interface stops in between and skips multiple iterations. So somehow `nextStep` must be blocking the EVT Thread, but when i check on which thread `nextStep` runs it always tells my that it is not running on the EVTThread (besides when using the `SwingTimer` obviously)

Any Ideas?

EDIT:// I've added demo files they can be run be compiling and running the Main.java file. If you are on *unix you can also simply run the 'run' bash script.

Comment: Since you haven't provided a short, self-contained, runnable example of your problem, my only suggestion is to read my article, [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504), and see one way to code the game.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Looking at the example you linked I can only find that it was implemented pretty much the same way i did it. Except for the drawing code. Still I can't find the problem with my code. I've added a Github link to download the program.